# pandas: asfreq strange behavior when including more data

Tags: python, pandas

I am having problems with using asfreq. As can be seen below, when I include one more value from the ts Series to do asfreq on, the result ts2 is to set all values equal to the first. My expectation would be that there is not change at all, besides potentially including one more new value. To me this seems to be a bug, or am I missing something?

```
In [571]: ts
Out[571]: 
2014-02-24 13:26:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:47:11.480000   -0.900430
2014-02-24 15:09:36.490000   -0.998898
2014-02-24 15:48:31.534000    1.242197
2014-02-24 15:49:32.529000   -0.301316
2014-02-24 15:58:41.321000    0.342022
2014-02-24 16:05:42.752000   -0.876856
2014-02-24 16:10:21.501000   -1.050685
2014-02-24 16:16:47.204000    1.391424
2014-02-24 16:18:48.296000    1.048143
2014-02-24 16:19:52.346000   -0.823974
2014-02-24 16:22:13.665000   -0.689560
2014-02-24 16:24:13.760000   -0.323252
2014-02-24 16:26:15.155000   -1.095331
2014-02-24 16:29:58.235000   -0.185681
...
Length: 4455

In [572]: ts2 = ts[0:2128].asfreq('10Min',method='pad')

In [573]: ts2
Out[573]: 
2014-02-24 13:26:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 13:36:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 13:46:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 13:56:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:06:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:16:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:26:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:36:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:46:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:56:26.941000   -0.900430
2014-02-24 15:06:26.941000   -0.900430
2014-02-24 15:16:26.941000   -0.998898
2014-02-24 15:26:26.941000   -0.998898
2014-02-24 15:36:26.941000   -0.998898
2014-02-24 15:46:26.941000   -0.998898
...
Freq: 10T, Length: 7076

In [574]: ts2 = ts[0:2129].asfreq('10Min',method='pad')

In [575]: ts2
Out[575]: 
2014-02-24 13:26:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 13:36:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 13:46:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 13:56:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:06:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:16:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:26:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:36:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:46:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 14:56:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 15:06:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 15:16:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 15:26:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 15:36:26.941000    1.142483
2014-02-24 15:46:26.941000    1.142483
...
2014-04-14 14:16:26.941000    1.142483
2014-04-14 14:26:26.941000    1.142483
2014-04-14 14:36:26.941000    1.142483
Freq: 10T, Length: 7076

In [576]: ts2.max()
Out[576]: 1.1424827552686787

In [577]: ts2.min()
Out[577]: 1.1424827552686787
```

Comment: ``.asfreq`` converts the freq on a regularly sampled series, you prob want to ``.resample``, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a series with a higher and regular frequency. The values should be padded (forward fill) from existing values at irregular timestamps. The documentation doesn't mention that the original series must be regularly sampled. The first ts2 (ts2 = ts[0:2128].asfreq('10Min',method='pad')) is correct (after 14:47 a new value), but for some reason, when I include one more value / timestamp [2129], all resulting values are the same.

Comment: use resample; asfreq doesn't make much sense on an index with out a frequency

Answer (score 0):

```
 data=[('2014-02-24 16:16:47.204000',    1.391424)
 ,('2014-02-24 16:18:48.296000',    1.048143)
 ,('2014-02-24 16:19:52.346000',  -0.823974)
 ,('2014-02-24 16:22:13.665000',   -0.689560)
 ,('2014-02-24 16:24:13.760000',   -0.323252)
 ,('2014-02-24 16:26:15.155000',   -1.095331)
 ,('2014-02-24 16:29:58.235000',   -0.185681)]

 df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','Value'])
 df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
 minutes=df.resample('1Min',on='Date').mean().dropna()

 print(minutes)
```

output:

```
      Value
  Date                         
  2014-02-24 16:16:00  1.391424
  2014-02-24 16:18:00  1.048143
  2014-02-24 16:19:00 -0.823974
  2014-02-24 16:22:00 -0.689560
  2014-02-24 16:24:00 -0.323252
  2014-02-24 16:26:00 -1.095331
  2014-02-24 16:29:00 -0.185681
```